# How can I write this to include multiple conditions?

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to write out excel files as workbooks where columns satisfy more than one condition. I receive errors here with grep function and unexpected }

If I remove the grep function the code executes with the first condition.

Just an example, if first condition == 10, good and If second condition = "test", good folder. Else, bad folder.

This code is embedded in a for loop. 'data' is the frame created in each pass, 'files1' is the name of each excel workbook captured and then written out to desired folder in each pass.

```
   if (nchar(data$`Serial Number:`) == 10) %>% 
     if grep(pattern = "test",x = data$`Product:`, value = TRUE){
      write_xlsx(data, path = (paste0("good/", files1, "x")))
       }else{
        write_xlsx(data, path = (paste0("bad/", files1, "x")))
        }
```

Comment: Use `grepl` instead of `grep` for logical statements.

Comment: However, it is unclear how a *many* value column level condition applies to a *single* data directive. Do you intend for *any* TRUEs?

Comment: I'm not sure if I intend for any trues to be honest - wish I knew what that meant. Do you know what the correct syntax would look like to add the second condition? Thanks

Comment: What are you intending to do in human language terms? If "test" shows up in any or all rows of `data[["Carrier:"]]` column, then export data frame into good directory otherwise save data in bad directory?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve. Code Result:

- Import files from folder and preserve names
- Loop conditions to check for col1 and col5 - Do they have the data I want? If not
  move to desired path, if yes move to desired path and save while preserving the
  file name

Please, if anyone has suggestions on how to clean this up, please let know. I'd be curious to know how this could be improved on with piping. Thank you!

```
files <- 
  list.files(path = "mypath/", pattern = "*xls")

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  files1 <- 
    basename(files[i]) 
  
  files1 <- gsub(pattern = "'", replacement = "" , x = files1) 
  files1 <- gsub(pattern = "\\*", replacement = "" , x = files1)
  
  data <- 
    read_excel(paste0("mypath/", files[i])) 
  
  data$col1 <- as.character(data$col1) 
  data <- data %>% 
    mutate(charCount = nchar(data$col1))
  data <- data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))
  
  if(any(grepl(pattern = "input pattern", x = data$charCount)) == FALSE) {
    write_xlsx(data, path = (paste0("path1/", files1, "x")))
  }
  if (any(grepl(pattern = "input pattern", x = data$col1) == TRUE) && any(grepl(pattern = "input pattern",x = data$col5,ignore.case = T) == TRUE)){
    write_xlsx(data[,1:11], path = (paste0("path2/", files1, "x"))) 
  }else{
    write_xlsx(data[,1:11], path = (paste0("bad/", files1, "x")))
  }}
```